# Android: start maps with route

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation, maps, routes

I know it is possible to start google maps with a route of 2 points but I really need to start it with many waypoints. How can this be done?

And another big wish would be: (I really doubt that this is possible but who knows?)
Can you somehow put those waypoints information into an intent so that it isn't necessarily for google maps but for ANY navigation app? So that the user can choose his own navigation app...?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a way to do it with google maps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
    Uri.parse("https://maps.google.ch/maps?saddr=[address1]&daddr=[address2] to:[address3] to: [address4]"));
startActivity(intent);
```

(Replace [address#] with the waypoints)

The problem is that the google maps app doesn't show all the waypoints but only the first and the last. I'd really like to make all waypoints visible and to make navigation actually navigate you to the points and telling you when you've reached one, but google doesn't seem to think that this is needed...